# what way can i adjust the position of an skspritenode when it's frame intersects another skspritenode's to prevent them from overlapping?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development, skspritenode

I wanted to update the position of my skspritenodes to push them away from eachother whenever they start to overlap. I was thinking to try using an if statement to check for whether one's frame intersects another, but I am willing to try another solution.

```
var ships: [SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()
for _ in 1...5 {
        let barge = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BattleShip2")
        barge.setScale(0.1)
        barge.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY)
        addChild(barge)
        ships.append(barge)
    }
```

with this initializing loop i end up with 5 objects all stacked on top of eachother in the center of the view. I want them to all seperate from eachother slowly until they are no longer overlapping at all. This is where I'm at:

```
    var currentShip = SKSpriteNode()
    for ship in ships {
        if ship.frame.intersects(currentShip.frame) {
            // do something
        }
        currentShip = ship
    }
```

Comment: the built-in physics engine will do this type of behavior. or you can roll your own: (1) give each ship a velocity vector; (2) if two ships intersect calculate the vector between their centers and normalize/scale it down to get a small-ish push force; (3) add this push vector to each ship's velocity in directions facing away from each other; (4) apply a friction drag force to all ships over time via the update loop so the ships eventually come to a stop. ex: ship.velocity *= 0.97. oh and don't start them all at midX/midY ;) randomize the start positions slightly